# How to configure a GitHub repo such that one command creates local copy of folder and a tarball

Tags: git, github, deb

This probably isn't a unique requirement, but after some searching I have not found a solution for how to accomplish this:

Those familiar with Debian source packages will recognize this setup after installing a source package from an `apt` repo in your $HOME folder; e.g. `apt-get source pkgname` :

```sh
$ ls -l | grep pkgname
drwxr-xr-x    pkgname_1.2.3 
-rw-r--r--    pkgname_1.2.3.orig.tar.xz
```

Similar to a `git` repo, the folder `pkgname_1.2.3` contains all of the files needed to build the `.deb` file which then is used to install the application: `$ cd pkgname_1.2.3`, and go to work. What's different between the Debian source package and a `git` repo is that the source package also includes a tarball `*.orig.tar.xz` that contains the original upstream sources. This tarball must (should) be present during the build process.

I've obtained the sources from a package repo hosted by my distribution organization (Raspberry Pi). I've modified the sources to fix an issue, built and tested the program. I'd like to share my changes through my GitHub site, as the source package repo & release schedule is controlled by other priorities. From the user's perspective, I'd like for this to be as simple as this:

```sh
$ cd
$ git clone https://github.com/seamusdemora/pkgname_1.2.3 
$ ls -l | grep pkgname_1.2.3
drwxr-xr-x    pkgname_1.2.3 
-rw-r--r--    pkgname_1.2.3.orig.tar.xz
```

From my experience, I'd expect the result of this `git clone` command to copy only the folder (`~/pkgname_1.2.3`). I don't want to add a tarball to the build folder. Is there some way to get **both** the folder and the tarball from a single clone command, such that both end up located in `~/`? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `apt` is a *package* management system and `git` is a *source code* management system (SCM) (or *version control system*, VCS). These have different goals and methods, so it's generally not a good idea to try to use Git as a package management system. There *is* enough overlap between them that in some (limited) cases, an SCM or VCS can be used as a package manager, but unless you fall into that particular limited case, you want a real package manager. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems

Comment: You might consider setting up a "personal package archive" (PPA); then you *can* use `apt` as a package manager. (See, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) (doesn't seem to have instructions on *creating* a PPA, and I don't have them handy myself, but it's not that difficult once you find all the pieces). [Here's a better Q&A.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa)

Comment: @torek: Thanks again, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get what you asked for from Git alone: `git clone` makes a new empty directory (or takes one as an argument), creates a new empty repository *in* that directory, and then adds a remote and fetches from it, to populate the repository with commits. It then creates one branch name and checks that branch out, unless you specify otherwise. The result is that there's no tarball, and you have a full repository, not *just* the distributed version.